# Retrieve file from FTP, unzip file, save extract file to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip, ftplib

Attempting to retrieve a file from FTP and save it to an S3 bucket within lambda function.

I can confirm the first part of the code works as I can see the list of files printed to Cloudwatch logs.

```
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP
import zipfile
import boto3

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME = 'my-s3bucket' 

    ftp = FTP('ftp.godaddy.com')
  
    ftp.login(user='auctions', passwd='')
  
    ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

The next part was resulting in the following error:

```
module initialization error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'tdnam_all_listings.csv.zip'
```

However I managed to overcome this by adding 'tmp' to the file location as per following code:

```
fileName = 'all_expiring_auctions.json.zip'


with open('/tmp/fileName', 'wb') as file:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fileName, file.write)
```

Next, I am attempting to unzip the file from the temporary loaction

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('/tmp/fileName', 'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall('')
```

Finally, I am attempting save the file to a particular 'folder' in the s3 bucket, as follows:

```
data = open('/tmp/all_expiring_auctions.json')

s3.Bucket('brnddmn-s3').upload_fileobj('data','my-s3bucket/folder/')
```

The code produces no errors that I can see in the log, however the unzipped file is not reaching the destination despite my efforts.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: upload_fileobj should be passed a file object, not a string.

Comment: In the last line, `'data'` should be `data` (without the quotes). Also, the bucket name is given as `brnddmn-s3`, so it should _not_ also be included in the upload command -- presumably you should use: `upload_fileobject(data, 'folder/')`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, John. This doesn't seem to be working however. There is still no file in the destination. Can you suggest anything else I might try?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to use the `tmp` directory for working with files in Lambda. The ZipFile `extractall('')` will create the extract in your current working directory though, assuming the zip content is a simple plain text file with no relative path. To create the extract in `tmp` directory, use

```
zip_ref.extract_all('tmp')
```

I'm not sure why there are no errors logged. `data = open(...)` should throw an error if no file is found. If required you can explicitly print if file exists:

```
import os
print(os.path.exists('tmp/all_expiring_auctions.json')) # True/False
```

Finally, once you have ensured the file exists, the argument for `Bucket()` should be the bucket name. Not sure if your bucket name is `'brnddmn-s3'` or `'my-s3bucket'`. Also, the first argument to `upload_fileobj()` should be a file object, i.e., `data` instead of string `'data'`. The second argument should be the object key (filename in S3) instead of the folder name.

Putting it together, the last line should look like this.

```
S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME = 'my-s3bucket' # Replace with your S3 bucket name
s3.Bucket(S3_OUTPUT_BUCKETNAME).upload_fileobj(data,'folder/all_expiring_auctions.json')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this is stil not working. Were you able to produce the desired results yourself within AWS using the code provided?

Comment: @jimiclapton I didn't test it this time, because I would need to setup a lambda, but wanted to point out the major errors in the given example. Now that I re-read the question, the `path` in `extractall()` will result in the extract being in the working directory, not `tmp`. Editing answer for this.

Comment: Thanks again. I had in fact already noticed that and amended that but using `zip_ref.extractall('/tmp/')`. I'll amend as per your suggestion and report back.